# Filling list view from multiple columns in a cursor, but only one row?

Tags: android

Sorry if this seems stupid, but I'm sort of new to all this stuff. The situation is that i have a lot of data stored in a database that I need to present in list views. The first view pulls 15 rows and uses only two out of 14 columns in the db. I use this adapter to present this in a list view:

```
private class CustomListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private Cursor cursor;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, Cursor cursor, String from[], int to[]) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, cursor, from, to);
            this.cursor = cursor;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            if (cursor != null) {
                    TextView lt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lefttext);
                    TextView rt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.righttext);
                    if (lt != null) {
                          lt.setText(/*cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EwstableContentProvider.TIMESTAMP))*/cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EwstableContentProvider._ID)));                            }
                    if (rt != null){
                          rt.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EwstableContentProvider.TOTALEWS)));
                    }

            }
            return v;
    }
}
```

}

This may even be stupid, but at least it works.
Now, on the next activity i need to present data from all the columns, but only from the row that the user selected on the previous activity. I was looking at putting it inside a list view like the one from http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/, which is also where i modified the adapter from.
this way, i would put data from two fields in the db into each item in the list view. this is perfect, it would be one data point and a comment that goes with it.
The problem is that at this point i only have one row in the cursor, so the bit after @Override is only executed once, so instead of the 7 items in the list view, I get one.
I'd really appreciate any help, even if it is to do it in an entirely different way.

Comment: So you want a listview with each column of a database row as it's own item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you know the number of columns, could you just use a for loop to iterate through all the columns, storing each string into a String array.

```
String[] arr = new String[cursor.getColumnCount()];
for(int i=0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++)
    arr[i] = cursor.getString(i);
```

Then use the String[] with an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) for your listview.

Comment: You can simply use `cursor.getColumnCount()` to specify the `String[]` size and also for the `for` loop.

Comment: No problem....and +1 for use of `ArrayAdapter` which is what I would have suggested but you beat me to it. :)

Comment: Thanks guys, that worked after a bit of work. One note, though. Instead of arr.add(cursor.getString(i)); I had to do arr[i] = cursor.getString(i);.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: sorry didn't read the question carefully; see other answer.

You need to use a cursor adapter. I recommend the [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) (example below).

You will also need to change the "from" parameter to the column name (key) for the text you want displayed. An example from my personal code is below. This line,

```
new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_NAME },
```

is the important one. It is defined in DBAdapter to be:

```
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
```

which matches the name of the first column in my own database.

```
DBAdapter dba = new DBAdapter(this);
    dba.open();
    Cursor c = dba.list_listMode();

    SimpleCursorAdapter ca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.list_item,
            c,
            new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_NAME },
            new int[] { R.id.list_item_text });

    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setAdapter(ca);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id_long) {
```